# Numpy: Find unique maxima along both axes of 2d matrix

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

Given an `n` by `n` square matrix `M`, how to efficiently find all `(i,j)`, `0 <= i,j < n` where there is no `k`, `0 <= k < n` such that:

1. `M[i,j] < M[k,j]`
2. `M[i,j] < M[i,k]`
3. `M[i,j] < M[j,k]`
4. `M[i,j] < M[k,i]`

We can assume that the matrix is upper diagonal with `M[i,i] == 0` for all `i`.

I'd like the best algorithm for that and the fastest implementation with numpy/Python.

I have tried the following:

```
maxcol = np.argmax(scores,axis=1)
maxrow = np.argmax(scores,axis=0)

pairs = []
seen  = set([])

for i1 in xrange(M.shape[0]):
    j1 = maxcol[i]
    if (not i1 in seen) and maxrow[j1] == i1:
        seen.add(j1)
        i2 = j1
        j2 = maxcol[i2]
        if (not j1 in seen) and maxrow[j2] == i2 and M[i2,j2] > M[i1,j1]:
            pairs.append([i2,j2])
            seen.add(j2)
        else:
            pairs.append([i1,j1])
```

But it seems rather messy, so I distrust it. I was also hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: How do `k` relate to i and j? Do you have any solution, loopy even?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** code / findings.

Comment: can you give an example of a matrix and the expected output so that we can easily test our solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the following matrix as an example:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[0,8,2,3,4,5],[0,0,3,9,1,7],[0,0,0,5,4,7],[0,0,0,0,1,4],[0,0,0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,0,0,0]])
print(M)

[[0 8 2 3 4 5]
[0 0 3 9 1 7]
[0 0 0 5 4 7]
[0 0 0 0 1 4]
[0 0 0 0 0 3]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

The expected output would be something like:

```
[[0, 1],
 [1, 3],
 [2, 5]]
```

which are the coordinates of values that are the largest along the corresponding column and row.

This is an upper diagonal matrix with 0 diagonal. The idea is to compute the matrix maximum using `np.amax` ([more info here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax)) along each axis and compare the transposed matrix to the result. 
`np.amax` with `axis=0` will give you the maximas for each column and `np.amax` with `axis=1` will give you the maximas for each row.

The solution could be:

```
c = np.amax(M,axis=0) #maximas along column axis
l = np.amax(M,axis=1) #maximas along row axis

#comparison with transposed matrix
maskC = np.asarray(M.transpose()>=c) #mask of valid values for column maximas 
maskL = np.asarray(M.transpose()>=l) #mask of valid values for row maximas
mask=np.logical_and(maskC,maskL) # final mask

j,i = mask.nonzero() #keep only the coordinates where the mask is True

coordinates = np.stack([i,j],axis=1) #build an array with the resulting coordinates
```

This gives:

```
array([[0, 1],
   [1, 3],
   [2, 5]])
```

Comment: Finally tries this suggestion, but it does not seem to produce the expected results, i.e. getting multiple `j` for the same `i`.